# Re-enable link after disable_with and send_data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, download

I have the following link:

```
<%= link_to download_media_partnership_path(@partner, m: m.id), data: {disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin media-icon'></i>"} do%>
  <i class="fa fa-download media-icon download" id=""></i>
<% end %>
```

When clicked it runs this method in the controller:

```
def download_media
  @media = TeamMedia.find(params[:m])
  @file_data = open(@media.attachment.url)
  send_data @file_data.read, filename: "UH-#{@partner.subdomain.upcase}-#{@media.id}", type: @media.attachment.content_type, disposition: 'attachment'
end
```

This works fine but `disable_with` is still rendered even when the download pop box appears. How can I remove `disable_with` once the `send_data` method runs?

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following added to your `application.js`

```
$.rails.enableElement($('a[data-disable-with]'));
```

If you use `turbolinks` then will look like this

```
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
   $.rails.enableElement($('a[data-disable-with]'));
});
```

Hope it helps